# A regretful word

Tags: riddle, word

> If I'd just listen to myself,
>   I'd impose my ways,
>   I'd intimidate,
>   I'd even make cows fall asleep!
>   But I can just clear, smoothen or level.

What am I?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Are you a

> bulldozer

I'd impose my ways, I'd intimidate,

> A bulldozer is an aggressive person

I'd even make cows fall asleep!

> A bull (male cow) dozer (sleeper)

But I can just clear, smoothen or level.

> It is a vehicle which has a strong front for clearing ground